# Why does a Data Loader extraction fail when invalid custom fields are specified?

Tags: data-loader, dataloader-batch

I'm still trying to figure this one out but I'd like to know why a Data Loader extraction completely fails when invalid custom fields are added to the 'sfdc.extractionSOQL' parameter of the process-conf file. My trace output shows no errors nor provides a reason why the extraction process fails. I just wind up with a file containing zero bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Why does a Data Loader extraction fail when invalid custom fields are specified?

Because it is supposed to **fail**. And the failure message that you will receive whenever you specify an incorrect field will be as below:

> No such field [field name] on entity [object name]

Further, for:

> My trace output shows no errors nor provides a reason why the
> extraction process fails.

These errors are generated at the application level (in this case its the data loader). In event of any failures, the error messages are displayed on the console from where you are running the process. However, there is no option though to capture such failures by specifying any specific file in your local folder. **But,** you can see any such failures in a file called **sdl.log** which is generated by data loader in the **temp** directory. Refer to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_troubleshooting.htm) for details. Excerpt from the link below:

> The log file, **sdl.log**, contains a detailed chronological list of Data Loader log entries......The log file can be opened with commonly available text editor programs, such as Microsoft Notepad.
>
> If you are using Data Loader for **Windows**, view the log file by entering **%TEMP%\sdl.log** in either the Run dialog or the Windows Explorer address bar.
>
> If you are using Data Loader for **Mac OSX**, view the log file by opening terminal and entering open **$TMPDIR/sdl.log**.

Comment: Thanks Jayant. Do you happen to know where I can find documentation discussing its designation to fail? Whatever I have so far isn't in-depth enough.

Comment: I didn't quite follow, are you looking for the documentation on why it fails when invalid fields are mentioned in the soql?

Comment: Yes. I went through what Salesforce had online and multiple learning books, however none of them mentioned this, so I'm suspectiing what I have so far doesn't cover the in-depth info I need

Comment: Well I haven't really seen any exception repository kind of documentation by Salesforce. But this (and for most of others) is kind of a self explanatory and if you look around, based on developers like us, this exception says that you are trying to access a field which does not really exist on the object.